# Can anyone please tell me how efficient Azure Databricks Jobs are?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, databricks-workflows

like If I schedule a databricks notebook to run via Jobs and Azure Data Factory, which one would be more efficient and why?

Answer (score 0):

There are few cases when Databricks Workflows (former Jobs) are more efficient to use than ADF:

- ADF still uses Jobs API 2.0 for submission of ephemeral jobs that doesn't support setting of default access control lists
- If you have a job consisting of several tasks, Databricks has an option of [cluster reuse](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/02/04/saving-time-and-costs-with-cluster-reuse-in-databricks-jobs.html) that allow to use the same cluster(s) to run multiple subtasks, and don't wait to creation of new clusters as in case when subtasks are scheduled from ADF
- You can more efficiently share a [context between subtasks](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/08/02/sharing-context-between-tasks-in-databricks-workflows.html) when using Databricks Workflows